# update a dataframe at indices returned by query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to have query return a view so that I can modify fields without generating this error.

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

I have a multiline (long) query `q` that I abbreviated here:

```
df1 = pd.Dataframe(...)
q = "tcpstream==1  and ipsrc=='10.0.0.1' and sport==5201"
df = df1.query(q)    
df['dest'] = "toto"   # <--- this generates the warning/error
```

Apparently I could do a df1.update(df) but it seems like a waste, I am looking for something more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is designed for querying, not setting values. If you want to use string queries as masks, you can calculate the index and feed into [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.query(q).index, 'dest'] = 'toto'
```